# To use GPU computation with hh.exe

Tags: windows-10, gpu, chm

I would like to improve the search speed in my CHM documents in Windows 10 by GPU computation (etc NVIDIA 970):

- for visualizing the search matches in many views

I cannot agree with the comment that [CHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) is rejected, since Microsoft has supported well in integrating the format to new devices.

How can you use GPU computation with hh.exe?

Comment: What you want is simply not possible unless the application supports doing so.  Given .CHM documents are basically retired by Microsoft the process that handles it simply does not support it.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you, please, propose a better fileformat than CHM for searching big documents. PDF is not enough.

Comment: Does not compute.  CHM isn't designed for big documents Word and PDF are.

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot agree with your statement about CHM. CHM is not rejected: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help. It is support is actually still growing. PDF is designed for publishing. It is horrible in searching documents of having pages 1 000 000, for instance. CHM does still well. Word is also not scalable for that.

Comment: Your recent edit, adding "for visualizing the search matches in many views", radically changes the question. And is very, very strange. Your question was about improving search speed, but now seems to be about rendering the matches. Your GPU is already used for rendering the graphical user interface.

Answer (score 4):

It can't be done, and it won't help.  Simple plain-text searching is so fast that the limiting factor is how fast the data can be read off the drive, not how fast the CPU can process it.

Comment: Jacktrader proposes that the limiting factor is the rendering of images, not text. So using GPU for that could improve the limiting factor. I think jacktrader is right.

Answer (score 1):

You could I guess by making an exe compiled from say Python that makes GPU usage pretty easy but I think if that's the road you are heading down, you're doing something wrong. I can only speculate but I'm guessing you are running a CHM file from the web and/or UNC path? I know this causes a lot of problems and maybe it's not your case but if a CHM is too slow to render images, you probably need to convert it altogether to something else and that would probably be a webpage of some sort (then you could control everything better, pre-cache images and load only thumbnails as needed but ability to load full images). I really don't know, this is a strange question.. but even a structured PDF document would probably be a much better approach. Good luck!

Comment: Excellent point about the rendering of the images! I think it is the limiting factor, not the text. Can you give any code example?